# Importar um arquivo que comece com números no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Estou tentando importar um modulo no Python. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import 01_Jogo
print("----------------------------------------")
print("Bem vindo ao jogo!")
print("----------------------------------------")
print("Adivinhação (1) Forca (2)")

jogo = int(input("Qual jogo? "))

if (jogo == 1):
    print("Jogando Adivinhação")
    Jogo.jogar_advinhacao()
elif(jogo == 2):
    print("Jogando Forca")
    jogar_foca()
```

O problema esta no *import* que não esta reconhecendo o arquivo que também é *.py*, mas que começa com uma numeração. Ao rodar o código é apresentado o seguinte erro: **SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal**. Também já tentei colocar *import "01_Jogo" tive outro erro: **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**. Não consegui encontra uma solução para isso na documentação e nem regras de que não posso fazer import com arquivos que inicie com número. Alguém sabe o porque esta acontecendo esse erro e como posso soluciona-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema interessante...

Você pode fazer assim:

```
jogo_01 = __import__('01_Jogo')
```

e acredito que dessa forma também funcione:

```
import 01_Jogo as meu_modulo
```